# Linking external libraries using MASM

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32, irvine32

I have an assembly project I've written using Visual Studio 2015.

The project depends on 2 external libraries. I have included them both at the top of my `.asm` file like this:

```
include lib\Irvine\Irvine32.inc
includelib lib\Irvine\Irvine32.lib

include lib\masm32\include\winmm.inc
includelib lib\masm32\lib\winmm.lib
```

When I compile and run the project in Visual Studio, there are no errors and the program runs the way it's supposed to.

But when I try to compile from the command line:

```
ml /c /coff /Cp pacman.asm /I lib/Irvine /I lib\masm32\lib
link pacman.obj \lib\Irvine\Irvine32.lib lib\masm32\lib\winnm.lib /subsystem:console
```

I get a whole bunch of errors that look like this:

```
pacman.obj:pacman.asm:(.text+0x51): undefined reference to `_ExitProcess@4'
```

where `ExitProcess` is the name of a procedure from somewhere inside masm32.

I tried looking into the project and solution files to see if I was missing anything but I couldn't figure it out.

What is VS doing that I'm not?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162262/discussion-on-question-by-calicawesome-linking-external-libraries-using-masm).

Answer (score 2):

Add explicitly the libs (kernel32 and user32) where the functions are defined:

```
...
includelib lib\Irvine\Irvine32.lib
includelib lib\Irvine\Kernel32.lib
includelib lib\Irvine\User32.lib
...
```

You can use instead the MASM32 libs:

```
includelib lib\masm32\lib\winmm.lib
includelib lib\masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
includelib lib\masm32\lib\user32.lib
```

Check the path! You're using relative paths.

Comment: or we can use libs just from ms sdk